# How can I make empty circle on baseball out count?

Tags: ios, rating

I am making baseball outcount code based on FoodTracker source code. Here's my code but empty circle doesn't count in this code. How can I make the empty circle rating? I would appreciate if you guys can help me out. Thank you!!

///////

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {
    // MARK: Properties

    var rating = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
    var spacing = 3
    var circles = 3

    // MARK: Initialization

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let filledCircleImage = UIImage(named: "checkedRed")
        let emptyCircleImage = UIImage(named: "UncheckedRed")

        for _ in 0..<3 {
            let button = UIButton()

            button.setImage(emptyCircleImage, forState: .Normal)
            button.setImage(filledCircleImage, forState: .Selected)
            button.setImage(filledCircleImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

            button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            ratingButtons += [button]
            addSubview(button)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Set the button's width and height to a square the size of the frame's height.
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)

        // Offset each button's origin by the length of the button plus spacing.
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
            buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (buttonSize + spacing))
            button.frame = buttonFrame
        }
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        let width = (buttonSize + spacing) * circles

        return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {


            rating = ratingButtons.indexOf(button)! + 1
            updateButtonSelectionStates()

           }

    func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
            // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button should be selected.
            button.selected = index < rating
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want zero to count then return 0 as a possible button action. Your rating is already set to zero so technically it does count. If you accidentally tap the first circle and want to undo it you can try something like this in ratingButtonTapped

```
//rating = ratingButtons.index(of: button)! + 1
rating = (rating == 1) && (ratingButtons.index(of: button) == 0) ? 0 : (ratingButtons.index(of: button)! + 1)
```